# Where are actions of buttons' long pressing stored?

Tags: settings, system, customization, buttons

I want to remap the long press action  of the menu button to open the dialog box that appears when the power button is long pressed. I know the keybinds are stored mainly in `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` but I can't find where the **long press** settings are stored.

The settings menu allows me to remap the action of long pressing, but it doesn't offer an option to invoke the dialog box of power menu. As far as I am concerned, the Android API doesn't provide any option to access the power button so I need to change the action inside proper system files. Also, the API doesn't allow me to map the screenshot taking what is the main purpose of mine. So I want either to map the dialog box of power menu or screenshot taking to the long press action of menu button.

I own Samsung Galaxy S3 with Cyanogenmod 14.1 Android 7.1.1

Comment: Have you considered an app that doesn't something similar?  I think this question would be better asked on cygaogenmod forums but I have not done this before.

Comment: In the meantime I found an excellent app that does the job. _Button Mapper: Remap your keys_ can even assign the power menu dialog to individual buttons. It doesn't require xposed framework nor even root access. I just read that this is not possible without xposed so I didn't look for such application. Problem solved. Needlessly asked I this question.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer or allow me to post this as answer to the question?

Comment: If you find this necessary feel free to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So there appears to be several apps on the app store.

[Button Mapper: Remap your keys](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton) is one such example.
[Buttons remapper (no root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irishin.buttonsremapper) is another.